# Exit nightwatch cucumber process with exit code 0?

Tags: cucumber, nightwatch.js

Is it possible to exit nightwatch-cucumber with an exit code of 0 even when the tests fail?

Reason being, with the breaking changes you can no longer generate a cucumber report in a step, meaning you have to wait for the tests to finish, pass or fail, to generate the report.

The problem is that teamcity sees test failures and will not progress to the next step, due to the tests failing with an exit code not equal to 0, thus not generating the cucumber report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to run cucumber report generation from NPM instead a separate Teamcity task. See the [`nightwatch-cucumber` docs](http://mucsi96.github.io/nightwatch-cucumber/#html-reports) regarding this topic.

Comment: cheers, didn't know why i didn't see that in the first place. worked like a charm